# Overlapping pannels

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have two panels with the same classes but two seperate content. Whenever I click on the first link for the first panel or the second link for the second one, they both show up at the same time, creating an overlapping. I tried adding two ids for each one of them but it seems not working.

https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/VwammbJ

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" style="color:white;z-index:99999999;position:absolute;">

    <a style="color:white;" href="#1" class="reveal-up">First Panel</a>
<br>
<a style="color:white;" href="#2" class="reveal-up">Second panel</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-up" id="1">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">FIRST PANEL</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-up" id="2">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">SECOND PANEL</p> 
  </div>
</div>


<img class="ip" style="opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute; transform: scale(1.2)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431440869543-efaf3388c585?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
<div class="content" style="color:white">

  <h2 style="margin-top:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies aliquet quam quis faucibus. Maecenas at nibh hendrerit ex lobortis tristique. Ut hendrerit aliquet lacus, sed bibendum nisl dapibus non. Etiam eleifend eu ipsum at varius. Nam metus odio, placerat eu lacus quis, euismod finibus magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><code>ESC</code> - Close all windows</li>
      <li><code>R></code> - Open panel with pressing "R" </li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .content {
      padding: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 90%;
      -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
      transition: all .7s ease;  
    
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity:1;
      bottom:10%;
    }
    .content.hidefor-panel-up { 
        bottom: 20%;
        transform: scale(0.95);
        opacity:0;
    }
    
    .ip {
      display:block;
      width:100%; height:100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;  
      opacity:1;
      top:0;
      opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute;
    }
    .ip.hidefor-panel-up { 
        opacity:1;
        top: 10%;
    }
    
    
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
      background: #06113E;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      font-size: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    code {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      background: #efefef;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
    ul {
      margin: 30px 40px;
    }
    li {
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .panel {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .panel-content {
      position: relative;
      /*background: #efefef;*/
      padding: 30px 50px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .panel-content .close {
      line-height: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      color: #ffffff;
      right: 5px;
      top: 5px;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      content: "✖";
    }
    .panel-content .close:before {
      line-height: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      color: #ffffff;
      right: 5px;
      top: 5px;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      content: "✖";
    }
    .panel-left {
      z-index: 10;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background: #eeeeee;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      left: -100%;
      width: 45%;
    }

.panel-left.expanded {
  left: 0;
}
.panel-up {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  bottom: -20%;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-up.expanded {
  bottom: 0;
}
.reveal-left {
  float: left;
}
.reveal-up {
  float: right;
}
.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
.nav button {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}

.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS

```
// Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function (buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
      console.log('hidefor-'+panel);
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
      $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
    });
    
    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
      $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
            $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    });   
    
    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
          $(panel).removeClass('expanded'); 
          $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
         $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
      }    
    });
  }); 
}

revealPanel('.reveal-up','.panel-up', '.close');
revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');


// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
        $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); 
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { 
        $('.panel-up').addClass('expanded'); 
        $(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
        $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add unique id's for every `.reveal-up` and then modify your `revealPanel()`. By the way I'm not sure what is the function `revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');`.

```js
// Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function (buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
      console.log('hidefor-'+panel);
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
      $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
    });
    
    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
      $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
            $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    });   
    
    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
          $(panel).removeClass('expanded'); 
          $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
         $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
      }    
    });
  }); 
}

revealPanel('.reveal-up','.panel-up', '.close');
//revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');

    $('#open').on('click', function() {
      $('.panel-up').hide();$('#1').show();
    });
    $('#close').on('click', function() {
      $('.panel-up').hide();$('#2').show();
    });

// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
        $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); 
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { 
        $('.panel-up').hide();$('#1').show();
        $('.panel-up').addClass('expanded'); 
        $(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
        $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;  
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity:1;
  bottom:10%;
}
.content.hidefor-panel-up { 
    bottom: 20%;
    transform: scale(0.95);
    opacity:0;
}

.ip {
  display:block;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;  
  opacity:1;
  top:0;
  opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute;
}
.ip.hidefor-panel-up { 
    opacity:1;
    top: 10%;
}



*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background: #06113E;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
code {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
ul {
  margin: 30px 40px;
}
li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.panel {
  padding: 20px;
}
.panel-content {
  position: relative;
  /*background: #efefef;*/
  padding: 30px 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-content .close {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-content .close:before {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-left {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  left: -100%;
  width: 45%;
}

.panel-left.expanded {
  left: 0;
}
.panel-up {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  bottom: -20%;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-up.expanded {
  bottom: 0;
}
.reveal-left {
  float: left;
}
.reveal-up {
  float: right;
}
.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
.nav button {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}

.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" style="color:white;z-index:99999999;position:absolute;">
    <a style="color:white;" href="#1" class="reveal-up" id='open'>First Panel</a>
<br>
<a style="color:white;" href="#2" class="reveal-up" id='close'>Second panel</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-up" id="1">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">FIRST PANEL</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-up" id="2">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">SECOND PANEL</p> 
  </div>
</div>


<img class="ip" style="opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute; transform: scale(1.2)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431440869543-efaf3388c585?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
<div class="content" style="color:white">

  <h2 style="margin-top:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies aliquet quam quis faucibus. Maecenas at nibh hendrerit ex lobortis tristique. Ut hendrerit aliquet lacus, sed bibendum nisl dapibus non. Etiam eleifend eu ipsum at varius. Nam metus odio, placerat eu lacus quis, euismod finibus magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><code>ESC</code> - Close all windows</li>
      <li><code>R></code> - Open panel with pressing "R" </li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but you code doesn't work. The first panel is not working anymore.

Comment: The function  "  revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');. is from an old test don't worry about it.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo is `<a style="color:white;" href="#1" class="reveal-up" id='open'>First Panel</a>` you mean not working?

Comment: Yes not working. If you could modify the code directly I will be thankful.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Edited, is this what you mean?

Comment: God bless you man :D ! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. By the way can I know what did you do to achieve it ?

Comment: Thanks! I added a click function to each link, you can see it is right under `//revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');`. Accept this answer so your question is marked as solved.